# Better way to find interactive deeper element tag in xml?

Tags: python, xml, tags

I want to find the last deeper xml tag interactively. I found some other questions but they all bring me a fixed way to find it. I want to add elements always to the last tag interactively.

```
root = Element('soap:Envelope', {"xmlns:soap":"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-soap_envelope", "xmlns:aut":"Automidia"})

sub_elementos = [Element("soap:Body"),
                 Element("information", {"token":"ABC"}),
                 Element("data"),
                 Element("value")]

for elemento in sub_elementos:
    list(root.iter())[-1].append(elemento) # This is the way I've found
```

I saw in [xml Element Tree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) that there is a `findall()` method that supports Xpath to navigate through XML easily. I want to know how can I use it to find the last element with `last()` function, instead of `list(root.iter())[-1]` as written in my code above. This command reduces code readability, in my opinion. Some ideias how could I achieve this?

This is my final output:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:aut="Automidia">
  <soap:Body>
    <information token="ABC>
      <data>
        <value/>
      </data>
   </information>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Using `[-1]` to reference the last element of a sequence is very "pythonic" and therefore very readable to someone who knows the language. You can easily write a `last()` function to do that if you wish — it would only require one `return` statement.

Comment: "my final output" is not well-formed. There is no `</information>` end tag and no `<SystemSetFormAnswers>` start tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to change one tag. Done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree_elements = {'body':{}, 'info':{'token':'ABC'}, 'data':{}, 'value':{}}

tree = ET.Element('root')

root = tree
for ele,ele_attrs in tree_elements.items():
    root = ET.SubElement(root, ele)
    root.attrib = ele_attrs
ET.dump(tree)
```

output

```
<root><body><info token="ABC"><data><value /></data></info></body></root>
```

Comment: But what if I have some elements with attributes, like `<info token="ABC">` ?

Comment: In my case, some tags has attributes, as you can see in my example.

Comment: So make tree_elements a dict and add the attributes as the values of the dict.